# String equality test fails for base64 encoded sha512 digest

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have the following table

```
   Column    |            Type            | Collation | Nullable |
-------------+----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 name        | text                       |           | not null |
 code        | text                       |           | not null |
```

I insert new elements using the following INSERT

```
INSERT INTO table(name, code)
    VALUES('SOMENAME',encode(digest(gen_random_uuid()::text,'sha512'), 'base64')) ;
```

Now when I try to SELECT against the `code` field:

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE code='K5HUaRwxsXzkAl3NaWHbBkvnYEK/...';
```

It returns an empty set.

```
----------
(0 rows)
```

The puzzling part is that it seems to break only for **SHA512** *with* **base64** encoding , it works just fine if I use **SHA256** or if I change the encoding to **HEX**.

I have a feeling that it might be a bug, but am I missing something?